# Print Google Maps API V3 Directions + route description

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a webpage that creates a map-canvas and shows directions in that canvas (Google maps). An other div, displays the description of the route. For the rest there are many divs that display information, but i don't want those to be printed.

So this is what i want:
When someone presses my html button, i wan't to let them print out the direction on the map with the route description. When they cancel or print, they need to go back to the website offcourse. The map on the website is a bit small, but when users want to print it, i want to show it bigger on the printversion with a little extra zoom.

Is this all possible?
I allready tried to hide all elements en change some css settings for the map, but i can't get it to zoom in.(note that i dont have the marker locations globaly) And when i cancel or print, my divs are also gone from the html even if i show() them again.

example:

```
<div id"content>
   <div id="map-container">
      <div id="map-canvas">
        when the site is opened, the directions are immediatly drawn on the map.
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="route_description"></div>
   <div id="someDivThatMayNotBePrinted"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help, feel free to correct spelling.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with the working code so far?

Comment: It's a big script + it uses some php connections. It's for my thesis and it's a small part i want to have because it's made for bicyclers.
(generates bicycle routes with some parameters) so I think it's best for you to know that i have a map with directions drawn on it and i want to print it a bit larger then the width and height on the page itself.

Comment: Of course you shall not provide your whole application. But your javascript for the specific task you're asking for with a dummy map would be really helpfull!

Comment: ok, good luck!  Without showing us what you've tried so far you're unlikely to get anyone here to write your code for you

Comment: I'm trying to make some dummy, dont be harsh on me please

Comment: This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/MRHQ4/
Want to do: print the map a little bit bigger and zoomed in more.

Comment: Do you can use jQuery or just plain JS?

Comment: Do you know the `@media` CSS rule? There is a `print` media type in which you can define all CSS rules that you want applied on print (only). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: yeah, but i cant change the zoom with css

Comment: Right. Problem is the `print` function doesn't have a callback. I would see 2 options: 1) Change the zoom level before printing (but it won't go back to its initial level after printing) or 2) Have a separate map, synchronized with the first one and used only for print. That would probably work but sounds like an overkill for achieving what you want.